# Doctrine2 schema-tool:update, constraint isn't taking effect

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I need to implement OOP into an old project.

Most of my Entities are working just fine, but adding a Constraint between ***User*** and ***UserAddress*** just ends up in somekind of weird behaviour.

```
/**
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Entity()
 * @EntityListeners({"Entity\Listener\UserListener"})
 */
class User {

    /**
     * Id of the user
     *
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Entity\Address
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\UserAddress", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $address;
}
```

...

```
/**
 * UserAddresses
 *
 * @Table(name="user_addresses")
 * @Entity
 */
class UserAddress
{
    /**
     * @var \Entity\User
     *
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\User", inversedBy="address")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

If I dump the the sql using the

***orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql***

it returns the Constraint that would be added like expected.

```
ALTER TABLE user_addresses ADD CONSTRAINT FK_6F2AF8F2A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
```

Since the Query looks OK, I switched to the *--force* parameter, which also returns an expected result:

```
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "1" query was executed
```

And now the problem occurs. As I used the *orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql* command again, I expected something like:

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

But it returned the exact same SQL as before. I can re-do the process several times, but it just takes no effect.

Am I missing something?

**Update:**
Still the same problem, also tried with disabling foreign_key_checks and executing the SQL via pma

Comment: I have simillar problem:

 `/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7, nullable=false, options="{default='#ffffff'}")
  * @var string
  */
 protected $color;`

yelds this SQL:

`ALTER TABLE role ALTER color TYPE VARCHAR(7);
ALTER TABLE role ALTER color DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE role ALTER color SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE role ALTER color DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE role ALTER color TYPE VARCHAR(7);
COMMENT ON COLUMN role.color IS NULL;`

even if these are already in DB. After running these queries they success but after calling orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql they show up again.

Comment: @RaitoAkehanareru You are lucky that your SQLs are executed. Mine won't. Decided to recode the entire Project anyway. Rewrote the data schema completely. Now everything works fine, with a solid framework :)